# Importing data from xml to database using php loop

Tags: php, sql, xml, import

I have problem with importing data from xml to SQL table. The xml look's like this:

```
<MeasuringPoints>
   <MeasuringPoint ID="BaseStation" LastChange="2013-05-20T12:15:03.837">
   </MeasuringPoint>
   <MeasuringPoint ID="MiddleStation" LastChange="2012-08-01T11:47:33.160">
   </MeasuringPoint>
   <MeasuringPoint ID="MountainStation" LastChange="2013-05-20T12:15:03.840>
   </MeasuringPoint>
</MeasuringPoints>
```

Using php (`foreach` loop)

```
foreach($skiarea->MeasuringPoints->MeasuringPoint as $measuring) {
  $MEASURING_POINTS = $measuring['ID'];
  $MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE = $measuring['LastChange'];
}
```

I get this data on output:

```
BaseStation - 1369052103
MiddleStation - 1343821653
MountainStation - 1369052103
```

I'm trying to insert that value to batabase

```
mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO database_name SET
  base_station_last_change = '$MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE[0]',
  middle_station_last_change = '$MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE[1]',
  mountain_station_last_change = '$MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE[2]',
") OR die(mysql_error());
```

But this code didn't work. importing only one value.

How to insert those data to sql database fields?

Comment: Why are you setting field names in an Insert Query?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE = array();

    foreach($skiarea->MeasuringPoints->MeasuringPoint as $measuring) {
      $MEASURING_POINTS = $measuring['ID'];
      $MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE[] = $measuring['LastChange'];
    }

    mysql_query("
INSERT INTO table_name (base_station_last_change,middle_station_last_change,mountain_station_last_change) VALUES (
'$MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE[0]','$MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE[1]','$MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE[2]')
     ") OR die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: this didn't work - no insert to db

Comment: I thought you were updating a row..

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($skiarea->MeasuringPoints->MeasuringPoint as $measuring) {
  $MEASURING_POINTS[] = $measuring['ID'];
  $MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE[] = $measuring['LastChange'];
}
```